# Disallow search engines indexing of entire web site, while allowing to save meta title and description

Tags: robots.txt

We are using the following robots.txt on our site:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

We'd like to keep the functionality (not allow crawlers indexing of any part of the site), but we would like search engines to save meta title and description, so that these texts show up beautifully, when someone enters the domain name into the search engine.
As far as I can see the only workaround is to create a separate indexable page with only meta tags. This is the only way to achieve our goal? Will it have any side-effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this robots.txt, you disallow bots to **crawl** documents on your host. Bots are still allowed to **index** the URLs to your documents (e.g., if they find links on external sites), but they aren’t allowed to access elements from your `head` element, so they can’t use this content to provide a title or description in their SERP.

There’s no standard way to allow bots to access the `head` but not the `body`.

Some search engines might display metadata from other sources, e.g., from the [Open Directory Project](http://dmoz.org/) (you could disallow this with the `noodp` value for the `meta`-`robots` element) or the [Yahoo Directory](http://dir.yahoo.com/) (you could disallow this with the `noydir` value).

If you’d create a document that only contains metadata in the `head`, and allow bots to crawl it in your robots.txt, bots might crawl and index it, but the metadata will of course be shown for this page, not for other pages on your host.